# How to add Images into Resources.resx file at development/design time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know how to insert images into the `Resource.resx` file at development/design time. Can anyone help me? Because, when I drag and drop an image it doesn't load properly or when I use the `Add Resource` button I can't select an image.

In the Image you can see how it looks:

[image: In the Image you can see how it looks]

The Error message looks like that:

> Resource '_2__poison_dart_frog' could not be instantiated.  The resource value contains invalid data or has an incorrect format.

But it's just a jpg

I need help!

Comment: Delete what you have dropped, click on the down arrow of the `Add Resource` tool, select `Add Existing File...`, browse to the file to add. If the error persists, then the Image format is not supported. It's either not a JPEG image (the file extension is irrelevant) or the JPEG format is not handled by GDI+ (e.g., some grayscale formats).

Comment: Thanks but why did you wrote a Comment and not an Answer?

Comment: Because the information you provided is too generic. 1. Drag/Drop an Image from where? Explorer? A WebBrowser? Other? 2. *when I use the "Add Resource" button I can't select an image*: why? What happens? Is the selector not responsive? Generates an error? Other? 3. What kind of Image are you actually adding? As mentioned, if it's a file on disc, the extension is not relevant, since it doesn't say anything about the real content. -- If the comment somehow *answers* the question (i.e., solves an issue, whatever that is), I can post it as an answer. If you explain what part solved what issue.